# Replacing all symbols between 2 others

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a database connection string that can optionally contain a password, which would be between symbols `:` and `@`.

How can I have each password symbol replaced with `#`, using regular expressions?

**P.S.** I don't want to change the string's length, only to replace the password symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```js
var pas = 'ddd:hsjhjshdjhd@dddd:djhfjdfj@';

var res = pas.replace(/:(.+?)@/g, function(_, m) {
  var r = ':';
  for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    r += '#';
  return r + '@';
});

document.write(res);
```

---

**UPDATE :** As @Tushar suggested you can avoid the for loop by following method

```js
var str = 'ddd:hsjhjshdjhd@ddddSomethingElse';

// Add global flag `g` for more than one password
var res = str.replace(/:([^@]+)/, function(a, m) {
  return ':' + new Array(m.length + 1).join('#');
});

document.write(res);
```

Comment: When I run it, I'm getting `@###########@` instead of `:###########@`

Comment: @vitaly-t : there may be better way, as per my knowledge this will be better :)

Comment: @vitaly-t Maybe `var str = 'abcde:fghi@klmnop'.replace(/:([^@]+)/, function (a, m) {
    return ':' + new Array(m.length + 1).join('#');
});
console.log(str);`